# How to copy files (XMLs) from one windows machine to other using Groovy

Tags: groovy

Can someone please tell how to copy files (XMLs) from one windows machine to other windows machine using Groovy script?

I have searched lot of content over web but mostly found copying from one folder to another on same machine.

Comment: Can you do the copy manually via windows? how do you do that? via SSH? network file-system access ("shares")? mounted remote disk?

Comment: Please be specific about the problem you are facing and add the code you have tried so far.  Right now it's not clear if the problem is specific to XML files (or all files), to groovy, to windows, ...

Comment: Let it be any file (XML, or other format). Here is the Groovy code which I used to copy files from one folder to another on same machine. How to deal with this if destination file path is remote windows?

String sourceFilePath = "C:/Groovy_Copy/source/File_1.xml";
String destinationFilePath ="C:Groovy_Copy/dest/File_1.xml";
(new AntBuilder()).copy(file: sourceFilePath, tofile: destinationFilePath);